# Supreme of some functional

Tags: calculus

Let $0<a<1$ be fixed, find the supreme of $\int_0^1 f(t^a)dt$ subject to the condition $\int_0^1 |f(t)|dt \leq 1$.

Changing variable $t^a=s$, we have 
$$\int_0^1 f(t^a)dt=1/a \int_0^1 f(s)s^{1/a-1}ds\leq 1/a \int_0^1 |f(s)|ds \leq 1/a,$$
and if $0<a\leq 1/2$, we can take $f(t)=t^{(1-a)/a}$ as a maximal element...However, when $a>1/2$, what can we say about this problem?

Comment: Supremum, we say in English (and instead of «satisfying»,something like «subject to»)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "maximum element" is wrong: $\int_0^1 |f(t)|\; dt \ne 1$ and $\int_0^1 f(t^a)\; dt \ne 1/a$.

If $0 < a < 1$, $1/a - 1 > 0$ so the maximum value of $s^{1/a - 1}$ is at $s=1$, where it is $1$.  For any $\epsilon > 0$, take $f$ supported in $(1-\epsilon,1]$
with $f \ge 0$ and $\int_0^1 f(t)\; dt = 1$, and you get $\int_0^1 f(t^a)\; dt$ arbitrarily close to $1/a$.