# $\sup_f \int_0^1 f(t^a)dt$ where the sup ranges over continuous $f$ with $\int_0^1 |f(t)|^adt\leq 1$

Tags: calculus

> What is $\sup \left \{\int_0^1 f(t^a) \, \text{d}t \ \middle| \ f\text{ is continuous, and }\int_0^1 |f(t)|^a \, \text{d}t\leq 1\right \}$, where $a>0$?

It is natural to do as follows.
$\int_0^1 f(t^a)dt=\int_0^1 f(s)\frac{1}{a}s^{ 1/a-1}ds\leq 1/a (\int_0^1 |f(s)|^ads)^{1/a}(\int_0^1 s^{-1}ds)^{(a-1)/a}$
where Young inequality is used. But it is $\infty$!

Comment: $a>0$ is a constant? Do you mean $\sup \{\int_0^1 f(t^a) \, \text{d}t \mid f\text{ is continuous, and }\int_0^1 |f(t)|^a \, \text{d}t\leq 1\}$?

Comment: @GeorgeBrown Yes. $a>0$ is a constant.

Comment: @MartinR No. In case $0<a<1$. Here, we are subject to $\int |f|^a \leq 1$. Meanwhile in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090324/supreme-of-some-functional it is $\int |f|\leq 1$.

Comment: @MartinR No. $f(t^a)$ is then replaced by $f^{1/a}(t^a)$. not $f(t^a)$ here.

Comment: @xldd: Yes, you are right.