# Let $b>1$. Find the sup of $\int_0^1 g(t^b)dt$, where the sup runs over...

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

Let $b>1$. Find the sup of $\int_0^1 g(t^b)dt$, where the sup runs over all continuous function $g$ such that $\int_0^1 |g|^b \leq 1$.

My attempt: $\int_0^1 g(t^b)dt=\int_0^1 g(s)\frac{1}{b}s^{\frac{1}{b}-1}ds$. One can use Holder inequality to dominate it. But $\int_0^1 s^{-1}ds=\infty$, so we just are led to the integral $\leq \infty$. Nonsense!

Comment: How is this related to your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4225475/42969?

Comment: @MartinR We only consider the case $b>1$ now. And now no answers are reached for that my own post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0 < c < 1$ consider the function
$$
 g(t) = \left( \frac{1-c}{t^c}\right)^{1/b} \, .
$$
Then
$$
 \int_0^1 g(t)^b \, dt = \int_0^1 \frac{1-c}{t^c} \, dt = 1
$$
and
$$
 \int_0^1 g(t^b) = \int_0^1 \frac{(1-c)^{1/b}}{t^c} \, dt = (1-c)^{1/b-1} \, .
$$
Since $1/b-1 < 0$, the right-hand side becomes arbitrarily large for $c \to 1$, i.e. the supremum is $\infty$.